# T-SQL How to Create a new column as INT from Datetime column as YYMM or YYYYMM

Tags: sql-server-2012

which is the simpliest way to cretae new column and keep old datetime ?
Use FORMAT?

Result like 201805, 201806 or 1805, 1806 etc from column datetime "2018-05-15 09:45:00.000"

Comment: Why does this need to be in a new column? This is just storing redundant information. What problem are you *really* trying to solve?

Comment: You should accept the answer below

Answer (score 6):

You can add a computed column. Example:

> ```
> create table docs
> ( doc_id int not null primary key,
>   dt datetime not null
> ) ;
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> insert into docs (doc_id, dt)
> values
> (1, '2000-01-01 00:00:00'),
> (2, '2001-05-12 12:30:00'),
> (3, '2007-07-07 16:45:00'),
> (4, '2018-01-01 12:00:00'),
> (5, '2018-05-15 15:50:00') ;
> ```
>
> ```
> 5 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> select * from docs;
> ```
>
> ```
> doc_id | dt                 
> -----: | :------------------
>      1 | 01/01/2000 00:00:00
>      2 | 12/05/2001 12:30:00
>      3 | 07/07/2007 16:45:00
>      4 | 01/01/2018 12:00:00
>      5 | 15/05/2018 15:50:00
> ```

> ```
> alter table docs
> add year_month as year(dt) * 100 + month(dt) ;
> ```

> ```
> select * from docs;
> ```
>
> ```
> doc_id | dt                  | year_month
> -----: | :------------------ | ---------:
>      1 | 01/01/2000 00:00:00 |     200001
>      2 | 12/05/2001 12:30:00 |     200105
>      3 | 07/07/2007 16:45:00 |     200707
>      4 | 01/01/2018 12:00:00 |     201801
>      5 | 15/05/2018 15:50:00 |     201805
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=326ae66c0926046f1bf4c358e6f627e6)*

Answer (score 1):

Try below snippet:

```
DECLARE @datetime AS DATETIME
SET @datetime = '2018-05-15 09:45:00.000'

SELECT CAST(LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), @datetime, 20), 4) + SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), @datetime, 20), 6, 2) AS INT)
```

Output is 201805. Make use of `CONVERT` and some string formatting.

Comment: thanks, but how do I Put it into a temp table  #tmp where I have created an INT column called "Period"?

Comment: Yes, How to produce a NEW INT column ?

Answer (score 1):

I like ypercube's solution the best, as I'd have done it as a computed column too.

For the value, if you have 2012+, you can just use FORMAT like you said.

```
SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'yyyyMM') AS FormattedString,
CAST(FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'yyyyMM') AS INT) AS FormattedInt;
--Replacing "GETDATE()" with whatever your date is.
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Beware: [`FORMAT()` has a very high price](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/06/t-sql-queries/format-is-nice-and-all-but).

Comment: VERY interesting note.  Thanks @AaronBertrand!  (Big fan btw)